# android start another activity on click on item in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, onitemclicklistener

```
 OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container, int position, long id) {
                // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
                LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) container;

                // Getting the inner Linear Layout
                LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = (LinearLayout ) linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(1);

                // Getting the Country TextView
                TextView tvCountry = (TextView) linearLayoutChild.getChildAt(0);
            //here insted on toast i want to start different activity for different items   
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tvCountry.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
            }           
        };

        // Setting the item click listener for the listview
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira when i click any item in list view then i navigates me to another activity for the specified item .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which activity do you want to start?
The normal method is:

Intent intent = new Intent();
 StartActivity(intent);

Answer (score 3):

Add tvCOuntry in "EXTRAS" and retrieve that in next activity which is same for every listview and perform action accordingly. 
Use following code to start new activity

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position,long id) {
         LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) container;

            // Getting the inner Linear Layout
            LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = (LinearLayout ) linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(1);

            // Getting the Country TextView
            TextView tvCountry = (TextView) linearLayoutChild.getChildAt(0);


        Intent intent=new Intent(THIS_ACTIVITY.this,ACTIVITY_TO_START.class);
        intent.putExtra("Country",tvCountry.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    });
```

After that use following code in "onCreate" in next activity

```
        String passedArg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("country");
```

in next activity and perform action according to "passedArg" string

Comment: can i mail my code and u could do some changes for me

Comment: Sure, please provide your mail id

Comment: aabansode@yahoo.com and can u also provide ur mail id

Comment: check your mail @Aniket Bansode

Comment: i have checked the code and what if i there are multiple activites then where should i edit

Comment: r u there i am waiting for your reply

Comment: You can use if else loop to start multiple activities according to list item you selected. And just change the activity name in Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ACTIVITY_NAME_TO_START.class)

Comment: can u plz again reedit the code for me with multiple activtives

Comment: i would love to. But i have other work also. Please try once and if you get any problem then ask here. Please don't ask to write your code. I have already added file for you. Just give it a try. It's very simple. You can do this. :P

Comment: unfotunatl biography has stopped

Comment: plz kunal can u do it for me at least activites for 3 items in list view